# Как указать корректное прослушивание сервера и порта на express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Сделал свой первый RestAPI на Express.js и изначально запускал его только локально.
Появилась необходимость разместить в интернете виртуальной машине.

как мне правильно указать прослушивание в данном случае? что писать в PORT и app.listen()?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? 3333
app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server has Started on ${PORT}`))
```

сейчас базовая часть выглядит вот так, и cервер слушает на http://localhost:3333 соответственно,
а мне бы хотелось что бы он слушал на http://z-dis-localstn.hostpro.ru/, например